# When I use python3 in the terminal, I can't move around with my direction buttons on my keyboard

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, terminal

Like the title whenever I try to move around a command line in python3 through terminal, I get this `^[[D`, `^[[A`, `^[[B`, and `^[[C`. So I can't move between characters. What is going on?

Comment: Did you build python yourself? Then, did you compile it with readline?

Comment: Yeah I changed something of readline because I was having segmentation fault 11 problem, which is why I had to look for a solution and ended up changing something in python3.3. Is there anyway to get back>?

Comment: To answer that it would be useful to know what you changed.

Comment: I wrote this command line and executed it `sudo mv readline.so readline.so.disabled`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like readline is not installed or working. Try running `import readline` and see whether it imports. This is usually because of building Python and not having the readline headers. In Debian/Ubuntu, one can install the `libreadline-dev` package. Then if you have compiled Python, rebuild Python with `make` to add readline support.

Comment: I runned `sudo mv readline.so readline.so.disabled` on terminal. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to install **rlwrap** and launch Python with

```
$ rlwrap python3.3
```

Of course, this doesn't remove the problem but rather bypasses it.